# How to define the path which I surveyed 4 times?

Tags: point-cloud

I did a kinematic survey of a path. I automatically collected data with GPS every second while I was walking on the path (walking speed is not constant). I did 8 repetitions on the same path. Now I have 8 different point clouds for the same path. How can I define one point cloud from 8 point clouds?

The image shows how the points look in QGIS. I don't have enough knowledge to figure it out.

[image]

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do. What do you mean by "define one Point cloud"? You want to combine your 8 Point layers into one?

Comment: I want to create a point layer which is average of my 8 point layer.

Comment: I think you should digitize the path manually

Comment: do you want to average XYs (horizontal)  and Z (vertical)? If that is all the points you have, I wonder if that is something you could do with field calcaulator... make each iteration of X1, Y1, Z1, : X2, Y2, Z2 etc  of the path a field and calculate the average of the Xs, Ys, Zs to create your new layer of averages.